# Adding buttons,textviews from layout to java class

Tags: java, android, shortcut

let's have a use case that I create some buttons and textviews in layout and I'm too lazy to write something like

```
private Button sendMessage;
private TextView nameOfPerson;
.  
.  
.  
Button sendMessage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonSendMessage);
```

is there some kind of shortcut or macro that will generate it for me in Android Studio ?
Thank you

Comment: Next time you should better specify your question / problem and don't use *I'm too lazy* because people will be downvoting you.

Comment: Let's have a use case where you post a [better question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one of the following plugins:

- [ButterKnife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/)
- [AndroidAnnotations](http://androidannotations.org/)